# How to escape python block comments when creating vscode snippets?

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I created a vscode snippet for a a python function definiton and I am wondering if this is the only and/or recommended way of escaping the python block comments (""" """).

#### global snippets file

```json
{   
    "def ": {
            "scope": "python",
            "prefix": "def func",
            "body": [
                "def $1 ():
                \"\"\"\" \"\"\"\    "
            ],
            "description": "Python function"
    }
}
```

#### output

```py
def  ():  
""" """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify each line in a separate string of the body:

You can choose the kind of doc string delimiters.

The doc string should be indented (`\t`) and the body.

```
{   
  "def": {
    "scope": "python",
    "prefix": "def func",
    "body": [
      "def $1 ():",
      "\t${2|\"\"\",''',\",'|} $3 $2",
      "\t$0"
    ],
    "description": "Python function"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right, this should have been indented. But let's assume the indentation wasn't needed. How would you escape the block comment?

Comment: I just saw that you are writing the body as three seperate lines / comma seperated. Is that  generally adviced when writing json code?

Comment: @RSale You can combine them in 1 string with `\n`, but separate strings make it a bit more readable if you have many lines

Comment: @RSale You can choose the kind of doc string delimiters, you don't have to use `"""`

Answer (score 1):

I just saw that vscode has a built in variable for block comments.
The code after the block comment should be indented, too.

```json
"def": {
        "scope": "python",
        "prefix": "def func",
        "body": [
            "def $1 ():",
            "\t$BLOCK_COMMENT_START $2 $BLOCK_COMMENT_END",
            "\t$0"
        ],
        "description": "Python function"
```